# dibujar malla y sus elementos en python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

Quisiera saber cómo puedo graficar una malla de una membrana circular en python. Ya tengo mi malla generada gmsh, de ahí obtuve los elementos y la ubicación de los puntos.

Al graficar los puntos, obtengo esto:

[image: Puntos en python]

Sin embargo quiero obtener algo como esto (donde pueda observar mis elementos triangulares):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo hasta el momento es este:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



POS = pd.read_excel('malla_membrana1.xlsx',dtype={'ejex':float, 
'ejey':float,'ejez':float},sheet_name='POS') #Lee el excel con los puntos de posición
LINES = pd.read_excel('malla_membrana1.xlsx',dtype={'a':float, 
'b':float,'c':float},sheet_name='LINES') 
TRIANGLES = pd.read_excel('malla_membrana1.xlsx',dtype={'d':float, 
'e':float,'f':float,'g':float},sheet_name='TRIANGLES') #Lee el excel con los elementos de la discretización

mshPOS = pd.DataFrame(POS)
mshLINES = pd.DataFrame(LINES)
mshTRIANGLES = pd.DataFrame(TRIANGLES) 

                        
                        #DISTRIBUCIÓN DE PUNTOS
x = mshPOS.iloc[: , [0]] #Selecciona la primera columna del dataframe mshPOS, eje x
y = mshPOS.iloc[: , [1]] #Selecciona la segunda columna del dataframe mshPOS, eje y
plt.plot(x,y,'ro') #esto me grafica la distribución de puntos de la malla
```

Aquí se encuentra el excel donde tengo la información de la malla:
https://we.tl/t-cLQVZ7ws1e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Dibujar triángulos con matplotlib

Para dibujar un triángulo tenemos que unir con líneas sus tres vértices. Por ejemplo, supongamos que los vértices tienen estas coordenadas:

```
p1 = [0,0]
p2 = [1,2]
p3 = [2, 0.5]
```

Podemos usar `plt.plot()` para unir esos tres puntos con líneas, pero necesitamos pasarle primero una lista con las coordenadas X de los puntos a unir, y después otra lista con las coordenadas y. En este caso las listas serían por tanto `[0, 1, 2, 0]` para las x, y `[0, 2, .5, 0]` para las y (observa cómo he vuelto a incluir al final la coordenada (0,0) para que el triángulo quede cerrado).

Podemos hacer uso de la función `zip()` y el operador `*` para simplificar la obtención de esas listas, y hacer entonces por ejemplo:

```
plt.plot(*zip(p1, p2, p3, p1), color="black")
```

El resultado sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Dibujar la malla

Lo primero es comprender la estructura de los datos.

En el dataframe `mshPOS` tienes una serie de **puntos**. Cada punto es un par de coordenadas (x,y). Esos son los que has pintado en tu plot.

En el dataframe `mshTRIANGLES` tienes una serie de **triángulos**, dados por tres puntos cada uno. Por ejmplo uno de los triángulos podría ser el dado por los puntos `(1, 2, 3)`. Estos números hacen referencia a los puntos del dataframe `mshPOS`. Serían los que aparecen en los índices 0, 1 y 2 respectivamente en ese dataframe.

Esta es la pinta del dataframe `mshTRIANGLES`:

```
       d      e      f    g
0  290.0  291.0  147.0  0.0
1  215.0  290.0  147.0  0.0
2   69.0  325.0  271.0  0.0
3  211.0  213.0  126.0  0.0
4  294.0  339.0  204.0  0.0
```

Las columnas d, e, f son las que nos dan los tres vértices de cada triángulo. Observa que cada punto es representado con un flotante, que debería ser en realidad un entero pues es el índice del punto (más uno) en el dataframe `mshPOS`.

Entonces podemos escribir una función que, dada una fila de `mshTRIANGLES` pinte el triángulo almacenado en esa fila. Sería así:

```
def draw_triangle(row_line):
  p1 = mshPOS.iloc[int(row_line.d)-1, :2]
  p2 = mshPOS.iloc[int(row_line.e)-1, :2]
  p3 = mshPOS.iloc[int(row_line.f)-1, :2]
  plt.plot(*zip(p1, p2, p3, p1), color="black")
```

La sintaxis `mshPOS.iloc[int(row_line.d)-1, :2]` sirve para acceder al elemento apropiado dentro del dataframe `mshPOS`, usando para ello su índice (`.iloc[]`), y extraer los primeros valores (que serán las coordenadas x e y respectivamente de ese punto).

Finalmente podemos aplicar la función anterior a cada una de las filas de `mshTRIANGLES` con una línea como la siguiente:

```
_ = mshTRIANGLES.apply(draw_triangle, axis=1)
```

Para que la relación de aspecto no salga distorsionada podemos además añadir:

```
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6,6)
```

La figura resultante es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! he estado intentando implementar su lógica pero no he podido, tal vez soy  bastante novato en python. No sé cómo implementar el def draw_triangle. Pareciera que python ignorara la línea de código del def.

mshPOS = pd.DataFrame(POS)
mshLINES = pd.DataFrame(LINES)
mshTRIANGLES = pd.DataFrame(TRIANGLES)

def draw_triangle(row_line):
  p1 = mshPOS.iloc[int(row_line.d)-1, :2]
  p2 = mshPOS.iloc[int(row_line.e)-1, :2]
  p3 = mshPOS.iloc[int(row_line.f)-1, :2]

draw_triangle (plt.plot(*zip(p1, p2, p3, p1), color="black"))

Comment: @arduinodroid En los comentarios el código queda prácticamente elegido al perder el formato. Puedes editar la pregunta y añadir el código allí? En cualquier caso, no sé por qué no habría de funcionarte. El código que he puesto lo he probado sobre los datos de tu xls, tras ejecutar las líneas de código que ponías al principio de tu pregunta.

Comment: Oh! ya lo pude solucionar, el error estaba aquí: 

    _ = mshTRIANGLES.apply(draw_line, axis=1)

en vez de draw_line, era draw_triangle

Comment: ¡Tienes razón, perdón! Originalmente había llamado a la función `draw_lines` pero en el último momento la cambié de nombre y olvidé actualizar la línea donde hacía el `apply()`. Me seguía funcionando igualmente porque el jupyter notebook tenía aún en memoria la definición de `draw_line`

Comment: ¡Igualmente muchísimas gracias por tan detallada explicación que hiciste arriba! me sirvió muchísimo.